# How do I display an image file as part of an array with text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementbyid

Basically I am trying to find the most efficient way to simply add an image to each question. The text works fine if I just use that. But the images don't display and I am new to Javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

I have declared an array as follows: it should have an image for the question, an array of answers for the choices, and an answer.

```
var questions=[
new Question("http://path/hombre.jpg",["man","day","weather","time"],"man"),
new Question("http://path/day.jpg",    ["year","thing","part/portion","day"],"year"),];
```

Here is the function that populates the questions in the app. There is more code in js and html of course however I would like to know if there is a command or shortcut i can use to display the image along with the other text as part of a question. Here is the code for the function that works fine if it is text only:

```
function populate(){
if(quiz.isEnded()){
    showScores();
}
else{

    //show question and try to put the picture here
    var element = document.getElementById("question");
    element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;

    //Show Choices
    var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
    for (var i=0; i< choices.length; i++){
        var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
        element.innerHTML = choices[i];
        guess("btn"+ i, choices[i]);
    }
    showProgress();
}
};

};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
element.innerHTML = ('<img src='+choices[linkPosition]+'>');
element.innerHTML += choices[restOfContentLocation];
```

Or however/wherever you store the image path. I'm a bit unsure of where the problem is but try this.

Comment: The problem was in the element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text; It can display the text of the question however it won't display the image.